# Hover fade effect via jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, fade

I've got this class:

```
#right_menu a {
  color: #002C6A;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'DINPro-Bold';
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 95px;
  width: 205px;
}
```

And this hover css:

```
#right_menu a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'DINPro-Bold';
    background-color:#002C6A;
}
```

It's working. But i want when hover, get fade effect via jQuery. How can i do?

Comment: Read about [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) in jQuery docs.

Comment: @VisioN i read, thank you. But not working on my files. Maybe i'm doing wrong way. So, i must see a sample.

Comment: @user1213807: Please post what you have tried already and you'll get better assistance.

Comment: I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/KpEMc/1/ But not working on my site.

Comment: may be you are not giving the correct div name in your site, as you shown in fiddle.

Comment: @user1213807: You need to include jQueryUI to animate background colors.

Comment: @iambriansreed no answer, no accept haha see my posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this JS file jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js it may help you.

Comment: I've got this file: js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js?m53h8b

Answer (score 2):

it is possible that you are missing the JS file in the head section.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#right_menu a").mouseover(function() {
         $(this).animate({ backgroundColor:'#f00'},1000);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor:'#ccc'},1000);
    });       
});
jQuery(function($){


});

Comment: need also jquery ui library cause you want to animate background

Answer (score 1):

You could try using css3 transitions instead of jquery?

to accomplish that you would have to place this in your css:

```
#right_menu a {  
    transition: color 2s;  
    -moz-transition: color 2s; /* Firefox 4 */  
    -webkit-transition: color 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */  
    -o-transition: color 2s; /* Opera */  
}
```

the '2s' is the time the transition is using, in this example 2 seconds
the 'color' is what should be faded, this is the font color